# PreloadJS Loading Partial Image

Tags: javascript, image, animation, preloadjs

I'm using PreloadJS to load images for an animation. The majority of the time it works great, but sometimes a single image (frame) is only loaded 10% of the way in the blob that PreloadJS creates. I am passing an array of files as a manifest into `queue.loadManifest(manifestName)` Any idea what could be causing this and is there any way to prevent it? Thanks.

Comment: I'll add the clearing the cache allows PreloadJS to recreate the blobs which "fixes" the issue, until it decides to not fully render an image again.

Answer (score 0):

Are your images squared?

I had this problem once, the loading was failing(or partially working) because my images was way too long (the width was "neglectable" compared to the height).